# Current class for navigation not working, in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, class

I am having issues getting my current class working. I want the current page's `<nav>` button to be a different color. I have tried all kinds of different ways to fixing this. I can get the text to change color but not the background colors. Here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<nav> 
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a class="current" href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html"> Beer History </a></li>
        <li><a href="brews.html"> Brews </a></li>
        <li><a href="recipe.html"> Recipes </a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> About Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
li.current a{ 
    border: 2px solid #413B02;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: green;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
nav{
    list-style-type:none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 19px; 
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: "cinzelregular", Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 30px;
}

li{
    display:inline; 
    margin: 0;
}

ul#navlist  a:link,a:visited{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#E6E7E8, #654C36, #3D2210,#3D2210); 
    border: 2px solid #413B02;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;
}

ul#navlist a:hover, a:active{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#E6E7E8,  #AA7A4C, #D36700); 
    border: 2px solid #413B02;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}
```

Please help. I'm completely lost.

Comment: .current {background-color:#FFF !important;}

Comment: Because you're styling the `li` element with the `current` class, but you've *attached* the `current` class to the `a` elements; therefore your selector is wrong and won't work by design.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<nav> 
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a class="current" href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html"> Beer History </a></li>
        <li><a href="brews.html"> Brews </a></li>
        <li><a href="recipe.html"> Recipes </a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> About Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li a.current{ 
    border: 2px solid #413B02;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: green;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

this will be work

but i will be prefer if you do something like this

HTML

```
<nav> 
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html"> Beer History </a></li>
        <li><a href="brews.html"> Brews </a></li>
        <li><a href="recipe.html"> Recipes </a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> About Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#navlist li a { 
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
}

#navlist li.current a {
  background: #fff;
  color: green;
}
```